# custom built kernel module problems

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, kernel-modules, development

I have been struggling to find a solution for loading module ath9k into the kernel and I have met a dead end.

The kernel is 3.17.1 taken from kernel.org and I am compiling it in Ubuntu Trusty (14.04) 64-bit. The target ARCH is x86_64

After make all command is issued, I copy the bzImage & initrd (custom made..mounts proc ,sys, dev and exec busybox sh) to /boot directory and it boots up fine.

Whenever I type

modprobe ath9k

I get the no module found error and so I head over to the ath9k folder ( in lib) and
run insmod ath9k.ko, it gives an error elf file not for this architecture

But my .config file elf enabled by default (make x86_64_defconfig and I personally made sure)

the output for uname -a is:
Linux (none) 3.17.1 #1 SMP   x86_64 unknown

What gives?????

Comment: The best approach to this (imo) is to build Debian binary packages of the kernel image and the module image. Is there some reason you are not using your distributions default binary kernel package?

Comment: well nothing in particular. I just want to learn kernel developing the hard way. Just curious that's all.

Comment: running depmod should rebuild the list of available modules for your kernel.

Comment: @SuryaTejaKarra Take a look at the [Debian kernel Handbook](http://kernel-handbook.alioth.debian.org/), and also [kernel-package](https://packages.qa.debian.org/k/kernel-package.html).